# Mass renaming files, removing dots

Tags: regex, rename, sed

I want to rename files as to delete unneccessary dots. ie:

```
File.something.jpg -> Filesomething.jpg
I.Have.Too.Many.Dots.png -> IHaveTooManyDots.png
```

How can this be done? `find -name *.*.*` lists them all, but I've been unable to write an expression for sed as it doesn't support lazy regexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
sed ':a;s/\.\([^.]\+\)\./\1./;ta'
```

You could use it like this:

```
find -name "*.*.*" | xargs -I % bash -c 'mv "%" "$(echo "%" | sed "s|^./||;:a;s/\.\([^.]\+\)\./\1./;ta")"'
```

It's been sprinkled liberally with quotes so it should work with filenames that include spaces.

Comment: Worked, put all files in my current dir though >:(. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Robus: Did you use the version with `basename`? That was a mistake. Sorry about that. The revised version shouldn't move files from subdirectories to the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

Using bash:

```
find . -name '*.*.*' -exec bash -c 'base=${0##*/}; base=${base%.*}; mv "$0" "${0%/*}/${base//./}.${0##*.}"' {} \;
```

Using zsh:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(**/)(*).(*)' '$1${2//./}.$3'
```